# Using tHttpRequest to download an Excel File from Sharepoint with Authentication

Tags: talend

I want to download an Excel file from Sharepoint and use it as input for a tFileInputExcel component. tHttpRequest seems to be the only component able to download files from a sharepoint server with authentication.

What of course works is to download the file via tHttpRequest, write the response  to a file, and load that file with the tFileInputExcel component.

[image: Example, but I don't want it like that.]

*Example, but I don't want it like that.*

However, I do not want an intermediate file and use the "stream" functionality of the tFileInputExcel component. What I do not achieve is to convert the downloaded content into a stream that is usable by the excel component:

```
((java.io.InputStream)globalMap.get("what goes here? And where does it come from?"))
```

[Here's an example](https://help.talend.com/reader/QgrwjIQJDI2TJ1pa2caRQA/wZphtUXJPNp32p65z7XSgQ) using the tFileFetch component, but this component is not able to download from sharepoint with authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I extended the tHttpRequest component and created tHttpRequestEx. The new component saves a ByteArrayInputStream to the global map which can be read from the tFileInputExcel component:

```
((java.io.ByteArrayInputStream)globalMap.get("tHttpRequestEx_1_INPUT_STREAM"))
```

[I uploaded the component on exchange.talend.com.](https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplaceproductoverview:marketplace=marketplace%252F1&p=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F1590&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F1590%252Fitems%252F2741)

Of course this has the big disadvantage to use a non-standard component. It may be the better solution to stick with the file download, and use tCreateTemporaryFile to deal with the complexity of creating and deleting a file.

Comment: I took a look at your component's source code, it uses ByteArrayOutputStream like my solution. +1 for the custom component solution which is concise and reusable without having to write java code. (For people who don't want to (or can't) install a custom component, see my answer above).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by writing the content returned by `tHttpRequest` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` inside a `tJavaFlex`, then converting it to a `ByteArrayInputStream` like this :

[image]

Make sure you uncheck "Write response content to file" on `tHttpRequest`.

In my example I download a text file because I don't have a link to an excel, but it works the same. You can read your file as an input stream like this :

[image]